# rxplot window size

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to set the number of points displayed in an rxplot window? It looks like by default there's about a five-second window displayed, but I would like it to be more like 30 seconds, displayed in real time.

I expected to find documentation of this on http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot but it wasn't there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9412/rxplot-window-size/) by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the "--help" option with ROS command line tools gives you help on available options. Using it with rxplot shows you can use the -p (PERIOD) option to set the period displayed in the window.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2011-10-13**:
Good to know. The -p option was not an obvious guess, I think the help could be a bit more explicit. I thought it controlled the refresh rate or something...

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-03-14**:
Haven't tried it before, but you can provide a legend for the plotted data similar to the functionality in matlab. I guess most of the time the automatic default legend (topic name) is sufficient.

**Comment by [Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/237/nick/) on 2011-03-14**:
Thanks! Do you have any idea what the options for "legend" are? That one is a little obscure.